# How can a sentence (not a formula) describe a set?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

What does this sentence mean?

Let $M$ be a model and  $S$ be a set described by a sentence in the language of $M$.
In
[Paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eroquette/1975-RobinsonRoquette.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7naKOm6nuAhWLy4UKHRo5CwQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw17qUOrEFjVbNQMMMLJZcb9)

Page 128, part 2.4.

Comment: I'd guess it's an error and it should say "formula" instead.  But more context would be needed to be sure.

Comment: Its about enlagements..... page 128, part 2.4 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~roquette/1975-RobinsonRoquette.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7naKOm6nuAhWLy4UKHRo5CwQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw17qUOrEFjVbNQMMMLJZcb9

Comment: I think you should include a reference to that paper in your question and say where you are having difficulty with it.

Answer (score 2):

As Eric Wofsey comments, "sentence" should be "formula." I wouldn't call this a typo however; I think it's a deliberate choice to increase readability for a non-logic audience. E.g. consider the line on page $125$:

> The first of these principles expresses the fact that ${}^*M$ is a *model* of $M$.

To a logic audience this would be a terrible misuse of the term "model" (since $M$ is a structure, not a theory). However, to a non-logic audience the notion of one structure modelling another might feel pretty natural.

So really I think the situation is this: some liberties are being taken with respect to technical logic language here in the interest of readability.